# Send Keyboard Event Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, keystroke

I am trying to find a way to send keyboard events from my flutter app to a WebView that I have open in app. For example, the WebView has some JS code with an Observer that waits for key events to happen. Any idea how could I do that?

Answer (score -1):

You can use the [KeyboardListener](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/KeyboardListener-class.html) class and send the data on the WebView [javaScriptChannels](https://pub.dev/documentation/webview_flutter/latest/webview_flutter/WebView/javascriptChannels.html) property (considering you are using [webview_flutter](https://pub.dev/documentation/webview_flutter/latest/) package).

Comment: Would this work if you don't have access to the content the webview is showing?  For example, on the youtube website you can press space or k to pause the video.  So could you use javaScriptChannels to mimic a space or k keystroke to the webview?  Glancing through the documentation I couldn't quite tell.